# localization with @page directive

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

Can I use @page directive of blazor with IStringLocalizer?, something like this:

```
@page @Localizer["myComponent"]
```

I know that we can't use two of @ after each other but can someone give me an idea how I can do that?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to do this that way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer is you can't do this.

The `@page` directive generates a `RouteAttribute` on the class generated in C# for the Blazor page. You can see this in the generated code in `/obj`:

```cs
    [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RouteAttribute("/")]
    public partial class Index : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase
    {
```

This means the route is defined at **compile time**.

The `Localize` function uses the browser's language settings at **run time** to determine a language and translate a resource.

So how could it be done? The routes for Blazor pages would need to be fixed, but you'd add a set of localized routes for each language: this would mean having a "translation map" of localized route to 'actual route'.

e.g. `"/fr/indice" => "/index"`

This would be more an ASP.NET Core Endpoint routing issue than a Blazor one. You should find several articles on routing in this regard.

Comment: Thanks @Quango, that gave me some keywords to continue.